# Ideas to prevent double voting on Android polling app

Tags: android, polling, vote, voting-system

I'm designing an Android app which will involve an informal polling system for small groups of users to vote.

I am looking for some design insight about different ways to prevent users from voting twice on the same poll. The voting will be mostly based on trust within groups and an invitation link to the poll, so this security constraint is not critical at all but a UX plus.

I know about some of the solution approaches on web like cookies, IP-blocking, etc, and I'm very curious about how this can be achieved on Android besides the most obvious options: 1) poll creator and every voter must be a logged-in user; 2) sending different unique links to every invited voter; 3) disable Vote button to prevent double tapping, etc.

The framework of choice for my project will be Kotlin-Jetpack compose. Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Comment: The safest approach would be to require each user to create a unique account and log in before they can vote (Uniqueness can be his/her registered with the gov). This would ensure that each user is authenticated and authorized to vote, and it would prevent users from voting multiple times or voting on behalf of someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the disable option, because that gives feedback to the user, like "hey you already vote..." maybe you could think, also, in registration of the user and their vote, with email for example... but in combination with disable the button.

You can add another button to change the vote if the user makes a mistake or simply want to...